# The generated div table does not render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, networking

I am doing a React web app and trying to dynamically generate table based on the selected data (users from a time period). The user data is downloaded successfully. I am using the same approach in other page. However, this time it does not render.

Here is the code:

```
displayUsers(tableOfUsers) {
  let table = tableOfUsers.map(user => {
    return (
      <div className="div-table-row-titles" key={user.name}>
        <div className="div-table-col">{user.name}</div>
        <div className="div-table-col">{user.surname}</div>
        <div className="div-table-col">{user.email}</div>
        <div className="div-table-col">{user.tel}</div>
        <div className="div-table-col">{user.addedBy}</div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return table;
}

render() {
  const userData = null;
  if (this.state.volunteers !== []) {
    console.log("HELLO");
    let userData = this.state.volunteers.map(user => {
      return (
        <div className="div-table-row-titles">
          <div className="div-table-col">{user.name}</div>
          <div className="div-table-col">{user.surname}</div>
          <div className="div-table-col">{user.email}</div>
          <div className="div-table-col">{user.tel}</div>
          <div className="div-table-col">{user.addedBy}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }); // this.displayUsers(this.state.volunteers);
    console.log(userData);
    userData = userData[0];
  }

  return (
    <form id="form1">
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.startTime}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="div-table">
        <div className="div-table-row-titles">
          <div className="div-table-col" align="center">
            Name
          </div>
          <div className="div-table-col" align="center">
            Surname
          </div>
          <div className="div-table-col" align="center">
            Email
          </div>
          <div className="div-table-col" align="center">
            Tel. No.
          </div>
          <div className="div-table-col" align="center">
            Volunteer
          </div>
        </div>
        {userData}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

The user data is there, it is properly ordered, the `userData` is not `null` (it is detected as `[{...},{...}]`). Yet, it does not display. Any ideas how could I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

------SOLUTION-------

I have found the problem. The user.addedBy was an object (addedBy had other properties), therefore React could not process it. Solved!

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(this.state.volunteers)`? Is it the data you would expect? Also, `this.state.volunteers !== []` will never be true. Use `this.state.volunteers.length !== 0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the project this is a bit challenging to debug. I would start by simplifying the problem.

1. First maybe look at what you are trying to accomplish and break out what can be reusable components (Cell, Row, Column, Columns, etc)
2. Start building each section one at a time so you can debug each part one step a time, such as if you have 5 volunteers can you get 5 rows to show up?

Can I ask why you are using divs instead of a table?

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue due to scoping of **let** ??
Since let is block scoped and  **"let userData"** is within the if block, it won't be available outside {}.
Could you please try declaring userData **outside the if scope** or using var??